# how can i show html layout link in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

I'm trying to make a html ad widget using html package, but the widget just occupy space, doesn't display layout.

```
Widget _adWIdget() {
    return Html(data: """
    <iframe src=adUrl width="100%" height="44" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" referrerpolicy="unsafe-url"></iframe>
    """);
  }
```

I think it's because I didn't setup a layout showing, how can I show the html layout?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html check this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it, when using iframe, you should use not only html but also the external package html_iframe.(you can install 'flutter pub add flutter_html_iframe')

The external package includes the following.

- flutter_html_all
- flutter_html_audio
- flutter_html_iframe
- flutter_html_math
- flutter_html_svg
- flutter_html_table
- flutter_html_video

and you can use the following code.

```
Widget _adWIdget() {
  return Html(
    data: """
      <iframe src=adUrl width="100%" height="44" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" referrerpolicy="unsafe-url"></iframe>
      """,
    extensions: [
      IframeHtmlExtension(),
    ],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use ***[`flutter_html`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html)*** package to achieve your requirement.

```dart
Widget _adWidget() {
    String adUrl =
        "your-ad-url"; // I created a sample html page on codepen for result. You can provide your ad-url.

    return Html(
      data: '''
      <iframe src="$adUrl" width="100%" height="44" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" referrerpolicy="unsafe-url"></iframe>
      ''',
    );
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]